# Why do some phrygian dominant pieces end on the iv chord?

Tags: theory, harmony, key, modes

I was looking at Itzhak Perlman playing Shalom  Aleichem It starts (0:14) in E Phrygian Dominant with the i chord, but ends (4:16) in A minor, the iv chord.

I've seen the same thing happen with [Hava Nagila](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SPXDAX4Ci8) where they play it in D phrygian, starts (0:28) with i chord, but ends on iv chord, G minor (2:31). did it modulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the Perlman piece begins with the tonic chord of A minor; the entire piece begins and ends in A.

This piece uses A harmonic minor, it's just that that collection is equivalent to the E Phrygian dominant collection; the only difference is which pitch is tonic.

With that said, it is possible for a piece to begin in a key and ultimately modulate to its subdominant—this *does* happen in "Hava Nagila." In such cases, we often understand the opening of the piece as conceptually being a large dominant to the final tonic. In other words, the opening D, with a close in G, is just a big V–i (D–G) motion in G minor.

Comment: @foreyez I hear D as the opening tonic of "Hava Nagila," but it ends in G. The Perlman, however, definitely begins in A. The melody might begin on E, but that's definitely within an A-minor context.